# Как правильно достать фото из галереи если известен ее путь и установить ее в ImageView для просмотра?

Tags: java, android

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой когда мне понадобилось просто достать фото из памяти устройства и установить его в ImageView для просмотра... Сначала я попробовал такой метод

```
imageView.setImageURI(URI.parse("path"));
```

но тут первый подводный камень и я получил такую ошибку

> Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5312x2988, max=4096x4096)

Тут мне пришла идея получить просто фото в `Image` конвертировать его в `Bitmap`, сжать и установить как `Bitmap`.

И пришлось установить в манифест еще 2 строчки, точно так и не понял зачем

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Но получить фото в `Image` зная его путь я так и не понял как, поэтому решил инициализировать `File` указать путь при инициализации, потом получить из файла байты и их уже конвертировать в `Bitmap`, сжимать и устанавливать в `ImageView`.

И вроде как все получилось, но тут был последний камень, мне показало не фатальную, но ошибку

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

о том, что я перегружаю `main thread`.

Я так и не понял почему...

Решил для избежания этого обернуть это все дело в `AsyncTask`... И в итоге у меня получилась достаточно громоздкая конструкция и все всего лишь для того, чтоб поставить картинку для показа юзеру.

А и забыл упомянуть о том, что по умолчанию картинка выводиться на 90 градусов повернутой так, что пришлось реализовать функцию поворота картинки...

**Прошу совет опытных пользователей, правильно ли я сделал? или можно как то реально сократить код?**

```
public void ShowImage(View view) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>(){

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.aleksey.deleteit/files/Image/PhotosDir/IMG.jpeg");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


                long i = bis.read(bytes);

                System.out.println("Done !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + i);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            bitmap = rotate(bitmap, 90);

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degrees) {
    if (degrees != 0 && bitmap != null) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

        if (bitmap != b2) {
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = b2;
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

И кстати, все равно чувствуется задержка после нажатия кнопки "Показать" и до момента показа...

Comment: Почему бы не использовать какую нибудь библиотеку для этой задачи где уже все сделано за вас? Например Picasso, Glide, и многие другие. Но если уж так хотите сами загрузить, то вот здесь написано как это сделать наиболее оптимально - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: О спасибо! Хороший совет, библиотеки действительно очень удобные, я не знал... 3 строчки кода заняло всего, вот только я попробовал и смотрю, что ни одна не другая не работает с `Image` либо  `byte[]` на прием, верно?

Comment: И все равно как ни крути даже с библиотеками нужно в манифесте добавлять android:hardwareAccelerated="false" и вот это         android:largeHeap="true"
, а то пишет ошибку как я уже описал в вопросе..., но тут опять проблема так как я работаю с `Camera2Api` то она не может работать если в манифесте указано hardwareAccelerated="false"... В общем теперь буду пробовать сжать битмап... Может так получиться

Answer (score 1):

В общем в итоге я решил проблему использовав библиотеку `Glide` , она самая лучшая из тех которые я просмотрел, основное ее преймущество было для меня то, что она при работе занимает в несколько раз меньше хип памяти по сравнению с другими.

Вот [ссылка](http://goo.gl/fwkCZC) с подробным описанием, очень меня выручила, спасибо за подсказку @temq

Не нужно было ничего придумывать сложного и код занял 3 строчки

Сначала нужно добавить

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

и потом пользоваться вот так

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
.into(imageView);
```

Очень удобно и никаких ошибок